# How to display 2 types of database information?

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I am trying to get my application to display both the Title of a task set by a user, and the date they set as well. I can only ever get one or the other to display properly. How do I get both the task title and month to display at the same time without only one or the other?

I've tried using 2 different while loops, and having the same while loop set both views at once.

```
private void updateUI() {
        ArrayList<String> taskList = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> Dates = new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(Assignments.TaskEntry.TABLE, dbCols, null, null, null, null, null);

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(Assignments.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE);
            int month = cursor.getColumnIndex(Assignments.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_MONTH);
            taskList.add(cursor.getString(idx));
            Dates.add(cursor.getString(month));
        }

        if (mAdapter == null) {
            mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                    R.layout.list,
                    R.id.date,
                    Dates);
            mTaskListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            mAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                    R.layout.list,
                    R.id.task_title,
                    taskList);
            mTaskListView.setAdapter(mAdapter2);
        } else {
            mAdapter.clear();
            mAdapter.addAll(Dates);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            mAdapter2.clear();
            mAdapter2.addAll(taskList);
            mAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

The output should be a month in number form and then the title of the task set by the user.

Comment: You can only set Adapter 1 or Adapter 2 as Adapter for your tasklistview and depending on what you set as last Adapter you see their values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the adapter twice, only the second one will show in the list. Why are you using two lists if you want to show then in a single row in a listview?

there are a few different approaches for displaying custom data in a list view, like, [this one](https://www.journaldev.com/10416/android-listview-with-custom-adapter-example-tutorial). or you can simply use an ArrayList and add the data like this,

```java
String task = cursor.getString(idx);
String date = cursor.getString(month);
taskList.add(task+ "\n" +date);
```

or simply

```java
taskList.add(cursor.getString(idx)+ "\n" + cursor.getString(month));
```

and then set the adapter

```java
mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                    R.layout.list,
                    R.id.task_title,
                    taskList);
            mTaskListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked, and is a good alternative for what I was looking for!